# Samsung Ultrabook Np-530U4C-S01 High Ram Usage

Tags: ultrabook, high-cpu-usage

I'm using Samsung Ultrabook Np-530U4C-S01. Here is tech specs. (using Win8, not 7)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHy4e.png

So when i start my computer it has avg 2.5 GB memory. Here is task manager SS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UMJl.jpg

So why is that?

Comment: I'm failing to see a problem here.  Have you cleaned out the Samsung bloatware?

Comment: How can I do that? @Mokubai